# THREE js TextureLoader() not working ON DEPLOY

Tags: javascript, three.js

My project renders my background and this avatar with the below code but somehow when I deploy on Netlify, it does not.

Tried the `../../` and `./` and without, but nothing works. Any insight?

```
// Background

const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./images/space.jpg');
scene.background = spaceTexture;

// Avatar

const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('logo.svg'); //, color: 0x00FFEB 
const jeff = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: loader}));

scene.add(jeff);
```

Much thanks.

Comment: It will easier to investigate the issue if your share the directory structure of your project. It's important to know where the images as well as the build file are actually located. Also consider to demonstrate the issue with a live example.

Comment: Hi @Mugen87 I'm not sure how to show the directory structure, actually I think that is th main issue, where the images are located and how I call them. I managed to fix the Avatar one. Heres is the netlify is if it helps https://bigztar.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because there is no loading manager to detect when the texture meshes have been loaded while your app is deployed in production. First you need to create a loadingmanager and then pass in that loading manager to your texture loader. Like this:
`const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();`

`const loader =new THREE.TextureLoader(loadingManager);`

`const jeff =   loader.load("../assets/jeff.png");`

Also you might want to rebuild your app with the npm parcel package to guarantee it would work in production on a free hosting like vercel. So move your index.html, styles.css and main.js files to a source folder you will create called `src`. Install parcel using npm. Here is the command

`npx install parcel`

install three.js and gsap packages too and finally use this command to build:

`npx parcel src/index.html`

It creates a `dist` folder where a new deployable `index.html` would be. Lastly, add all of your image assets in your dist folder so you `dist index.html` can access them

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need a loadingManager to load a texture.

Comment: It currently works for me I recently deployed a similar project on vercel and had to follow all these steps to make it work. Try it out and see if it does not work then you can say I am wrong.

Comment: Also, I did not say you needed a loading manager to load a texture it is just to help detect when textures have been loaded from a url or are still pending. That very specific scenario